# Format cell style through c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am using following code to apply style to cell.

But Style "Good" is present in Office US edition.

In other language Office editions its name is different.

Is there any other way to assign the style

```
Range cell;
cell.EntireRow.Style = "Good";
```

I think `Workbook.Styles[index]` can be used to assign style.

but don't know the exact index of the styles : Normal, Good, Bad also will it differ in other language Office editions.

Another solution is to assign all style values manually.

but problem in this solution is to get all values of the styles Normal, Good, Bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used indexes to assign styles.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the Style named "Good" - Office 2003 has style names like "Comma", "Percent", "Currency",...

Is it one you've added yourself?

In any case, a Style has two name properties "Name" and "NameLocal".

I believe you can use either as an indexer to the Workbook.Styles collection, so your US English names should work in other Office languages.

Comment: I am using Office 2010 64 bit